# Powering Raspberry Pi and servo motors from a single power adapter

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, servo

I want to use a single power supply for a Raspberry Pi and 2 servo motors. The servo motors require 6V for operation and their cumulative current consumption does not exceed 1A. The Raspberry Pi runs on 5V.

I am thinking of using a single power 6V 2A power adapter ([like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LN1QQJY)) and connecting the motors and the Raspberry Pi in parallel to it. I'll user a simple voltage divider to convert 6V -> 5V for the Pi.

Is this setup good? Do I need to add additional components like decoupling capacitors or other forms of protection?

Comment: Do be careful when powering off of the GPIO's: It's doable with a good voltage regulator, but it bypasses the safety features (like the polyfuse) that protect the main input. Real easy to blow up your Pi with a bad setup.

Comment: Motors tend to be very nasty loads, and the "current consumption does not exceed 1A" claim is *highly dubious*.  Have you measured the current when a motor is stalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is **never advisable** to power something from a simple passive voltage divider except the very smallest of static loads.

And a typical 3-terminal voltage regulator won't work because you need >6V for a 5V output.

The typical solution here in the 21st century is to use a DC-to-DC converter like this [one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-3-15V-To-0-5-30V-Auto-DC-DC-Solar-Converter-Regulator-Boost-Buck-Module-25W/131161611984). [This is the solution recommended in the RasPi forum to your exact question](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=49504).

Comment: Correction, there are plenty of less than 1 Volt Dropout linear and switching regulators, in 3 pin packages or modules.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, what about a diode in series with VDD to drop the power to to somewhere around 5 - 5.3 V?

Not the cleanest solution and wastes power but easier / cheaper to implement. Would need to confirm the diode is rated for the current draw of the Pi which I think is somewhere around 500 mA. So you'd be burning up 0.5 W worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about standard model servos? Those work well down to 3V, and in that case you can run everything from 5V.

On the other hand, the motors *will* have nasty load peaks. The 2A power supply is definitely not a way to go, it may happen that sudden motor load peaks will simply reset your Raspberry PI. (I have this with a simple Arduino... debugged for hours.)

It is all the time a good idea to have a separate power supply for logic, and for power. :)